# How to get user type from the database for php sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm building a website and I want to retrieve the user type that is defined on the database and redirect the logged in user to a specific page. For example, if the user is admin, it will redirect that person to administration page, if the user type is X, it will redirect that user to the specific page for user type X.

For now, I'm trying a temporary solution since I don't have enough time until deadline (tomorrow). And I'm trying to get the user type from the database by running a database and php query, which is as follows:

```
             $_SESSION['login'] = true;
             $_SESSION['username']=$username;
             $query="select user_type from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
             $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
             {
                $_SESSION['user_type']=$user_type;
             }

             echo json_encode( array('result'=>1));
```

I can get the username and login status but when Im trying to get the user type, I get an empty result on the _SESSIONS array.

Whole php code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
    include("db.php");
    $con=mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd,$db_name) //connect to the database server
    or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysqli_error());

    mysqli_select_db($con,$db_name)  //select the database
    or die ("Could not select to mysql because ".mysqli_error());

    //prevent sql injection
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["username"]);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["password"]);
    //$user_type=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["user_type"]);
        //decrypt password


    //check if user exist already
    $query="select * from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) //if exist then check for password
        {

        //Pickup password to compare with encrypted password
        $query="select password from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
        $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $hashed_password=crypt($password,$db_field['password']);

         $query="select * from ".$table_name." where username='$username' and password='$hashed_password'";
         $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result))  //if passwords match then check actvation status
         {
             $query="select * from ".$table_name." where username='$username' and password='$hashed_password' and activ_status in(1)";
             $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
             {  


                 $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                 $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                 $query="select user_type from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
                 $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
                 if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
                 {
                    $_SESSION['user_type']=$user_type;
                 }

                 echo json_encode( array('result'=>1));
             }
             else
             {
             echo json_encode( array('result'=>"$msg_email_1 <br /><a href=\"".$url."\\resend_key.php?user=".$username."\">$msg_email_2</a>."));
                // echo "User Account not yet activated.Check your mail for activation details.";
             }

         }
         else
         {
         echo json_encode( array('result'=>$msg_pwd_error));
        //   echo trim("password incorrect");
         }
        }   
    else
    {
    echo json_encode( array('result'=>$msg_un_error));
    //  die("Username Doesn't exist");
    die();
    }

?>
```

If you can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type` but what is `$user_type`? You did not initialize it anywhere, so nothing will be stored in `$_SESSION['user_type']`.

You have to first fetch the result from the database, and assign the value of the result to `$user_type` variable, before you can store it.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_type = $row['user_type'];
```

Comment: OH YES!! This is a very big mistake! My brain is barely working at these late hours :))
However, I'm still getting an empty result.

I've changed the code into the following types:

1) $query="select user_type from ".$table_name." where username='$username'";
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die('error');
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc(result))
      {
       $user_type=$row['user_type'];
       $_SESSION['user_type']=$user_type;
      }

2) I took the $_SESSION part out of the while condition.

3) I put just the $_SESSION part inside the while condition.

None of them worked :/

Comment: Is `$user_type` empty as well, or is it just `$_SESSION['user_type']` that's empty?

Comment: user_type was empty. I found a workaround method. I added a dummy page that will retrieve the username from the $_SESSION and request the user type with mysql command and redirect the page instantly according to the user type. I have no idea how this thing didnt work on the same page but worked on the dummy page. But, as long as it's working and since I'm very close to the deadline hour, I will use this method for now and deal with it later. However, your comment made me realize my main mistake. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it! :)